# Cordova Platform Add Error Android

Tags: java, android, cordova, android-gradle-plugin, build-error

I'm using cordova 6.4.0 with node 6.9.4. I have android studio installed in my PC (windows) with SDK 23,24,25 and ANDROID_HOME, ANDROID_NDK_HOME, ANT_HOME, JAVA_HOME in my system variable. After creating a new project using cordova and then trying to add android platform I'm getting following error:

```
E:\Android\q>cordova platform add android
Adding android project...
Creating Cordova project for the Android platform:
        Path: platforms\android
        Package: io.cordova.hellocordova
        Name: HelloCordova
        Activity: MainActivity
        Android target: android-24
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Android project created with cordova-android@6.0.0
Installing "cordova-plugin-whitelist" for android
ANDROID_HOME=C:\sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 8.891 secs
Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-whitelist':Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (E:\Android\q\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\cordova-common\src\superspawn.js:169:23)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:877:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1
```

I uninstalled JAVA(JDK,JRE), Andorid Studio, Cordova CLI and reinstalled them. After that I'm getting same error. I tried removing whitelist plugin and it throw build error with exit code 1. How to solve this ?

Comment: Solved By Removing JAVA_HOME from system path.